# Will harmonics cause nuisance GFI tripping with a Kohler generator?

Tags: electrical, gfci, generator

I have a Kohler 20RCA 20kW residential generator. About 10 minutes after the generator starts some of the GFI outlets will begin to trip. There are 19 GFI outlets across both legs and two panels. I replaced all the original Leviton GFI outlets with Lutron and the issue still occurred.

Issues with ground bonding is often a cause. The power company verified that the ground bonding was good and correctly wired in the panels, transfer switches, and the generator. We also could not identify any issue with stray voltage.

Harmonics introduced by variable frequency drives are also know to be an issue. We ran tests to isolate all of the VFD motors and were unable to identify single VFD that caused the issue.

During testing we also found that the Shark vacuum cleaner beater will not turn on while the generator is running and occasionally the elevator will cause the generator to “hunt”.

With a quality meter we could see that the issue generally occurred under low load conditions (<5amps) while showing relative high harmonics.

Are the combined harmonics from all of the electronic devices in the house causing an issue with the Kohler generator?

Comment: That's quite strange, what make/model GFCIs was this experienced with? Also, this isn't a forum, so you'll want to reformat this as a question and self-answer (it's a very curious phenomenon, that's certain!)

Comment: I'd also suggest formatting into paragraphs. Currently, it's nearly impossible to read.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Asking and answering your own question is _perfectly_ acceptable here, however, we expect the question to be in the box labeled "Question" and the answer to be in the box labeled "Your Answer". Please feel free [edit] this to flesh out the question (a one liner like that is likely to be closed for lack of detail), then put the entire answer (with some formatting) into the Answer box. As it stands, this is going to get closed anyway, so go ahead and [edit] it. If it does get closed, it may well be reopened if it's a good question with a well-written answer.